# Cannot access array elements outside for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, for-loop

The problem:

- When I try to console log the array inside the loop it shows me that the result was added to the array. However, when outside the loop, I get an empty array on console.log

```
var ResultArray01=  [];
for(var gg=0; gg<ResultArray.length;gg++)   // ResultArray is come from another function
{
  IPFS.get.call(ResultArray[gg],function(error, result) {      //this function is about smart contract
  if (error) 
  {
    console.log(error);
  }
  else
  {
    ResultArray01[gg] = result;    //get the result, and store it into ResultArray01
    console.log(ResultArray01[gg]);    //it can successfully print the value
  }
  });

}
console.log(ResultArray01);    //returns empty array
```

Can someone help me? thanks

Comment: change the for loop to use the `let` keyword instead of `var`, because when the callback function gets executed, `gg` will be outside the range of the array becuase of Closure, for example: `for(let gg=0; gg<ResultArray.length;gg++)`

Comment: Your callback is non-blocking and ASYNCHRONOUS.  That means your `console.log(ResultArray01)` runs BEFORE the callback does.  If you want to see the value of `ResultArray01`, put the `console.log(ResultArray01)` inside the callback.  That's the only place you can use the value.  This is how asynchronous coding works in node.js.  You continue your code flow inside the callback, not after the callback.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, becauuse I want to render the value inside the ResultArray01 to an HTML page, it seems like the render cannot put it inside the for loop. How can I reach it? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jfriend00 mentioned in the comment. Your `console.log()` before the callback is being executed. You can make use of `promises` here to handle such a scenario.
This is how you can acheive the desired result.

```
var ResultArray01 = [];
var promises = [];
for (var gg = 0; gg < ResultArray.length; gg++) {
  promises.push(
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      IPFS.get.call(ResultArray[gg], function (error, result) {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
          // reject promise in case there is any error.
          reject(error)
        } else {
          //get the result, and store it into ResultArray01
          ResultArray01[gg] = result;
          // it can successfully print the value
          console.log(ResultArray01[gg]); 
          // resolve if everything is as expected.
          resolve();
        }
      })
    }) 
  );
}
Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
  console.log(ResultArray01); // it should print the desired result now.
}).catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

Comment: Amazing. Could someone also let us know the performance implications of using this method? Any other way to do the console.log?